# Outputs are truncated in a remote shell buffer over `tramp`

Tags: tramp, shell

When I run `ps -ef | grep python3` in my kitty terminal, I get

```
root      2331     1  0 Jun22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root      2667     1  0 Jun22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
suan      7613  7398  0 17:32 pts/0    00:00:08 python3 /home/suan/upload/getAllNoRepeatCommunicate.py
suan     12024 11421  0 16:49 pts/0    00:00:08 python3 /home/suan/upload/getAllNoRepeatCommunicate.py
user      15553     1  0 15:27 ?        00:00:00 dtach -c /home/user/.detached/session/53890835fb1e2c2323e0b8c5862840e7.socket -z /bin/bash -c { /bin/bash -c if\ TERM\=eterm-color\ script\ --quiet\ --flush\ --return\ --command\ \"PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION\=python\ python3\ tools/train.py\ -c\ configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml\ -o\ Global.pretrained_model\=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/best_accuracy\"\ /dev/null\;\ then\ true\;\ else\ echo\ \"\[detached-exit-code\:\ \$\?\]\"\;\ fi; } 2>&1 | tee /home/user/.detached/session/53890835fb1e2c2323e0b8c5862840e7.log
user      15554 15553  0 15:27 pts/18   00:00:00 /bin/bash -c { /bin/bash -c if\ TERM\=eterm-color\ script\ --quiet\ --flush\ --return\ --command\ \"PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION\=python\ python3\ tools/train.py\ -c\ configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml\ -o\ Global.pretrained_model\=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/best_accuracy\"\ /dev/null\;\ then\ true\;\ else\ echo\ \"\[detached-exit-code\:\ \$\?\]\"\;\ fi; } 2>&1 | tee /home/user/.detached/session/53890835fb1e2c2323e0b8c5862840e7.log
user      15555 15554  0 15:27 pts/18   00:00:00 /bin/bash -c { /bin/bash -c if\ TERM\=eterm-color\ script\ --quiet\ --flush\ --return\ --command\ \"PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION\=python\ python3\ tools/train.py\ -c\ configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml\ -o\ Global.pretrained_model\=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/best_accuracy\"\ /dev/null\;\ then\ true\;\ else\ echo\ \"\[detached-exit-code\:\ \$\?\]\"\;\ fi; } 2>&1 | tee /home/user/.detached/session/53890835fb1e2c2323e0b8c5862840e7.log
user      15557 15555  0 15:27 pts/18   00:00:00 /bin/bash -c if TERM=eterm-color script --quiet --flush --return --command "PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/best_accuracy" /dev/null; then true; else echo "[detached-exit-code: $?]"; fi
user      15558 15557  0 15:27 pts/18   00:00:00 script --quiet --flush --return --command PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/best_accuracy /dev/null
user      15559 15558 72 15:27 pts/19   01:53:01 python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/best_accuracy
user      51718 44912  0 18:02 pts/28   00:00:00 grep --color=auto python3
```

but if I run the same command in a remote shell buffer over `tramp`, I get

```
root      2331     1  0 Jun22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root      2667     1  0 Jun22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
suan      7613  7398  0 17:32 pts/0    00:00:08 python3 /home/suan/upload/getAllNoRepeatCommunicate.py
suan     12024 11421  0 16:49 pts/0    00:00:08 python3 /home/suan/upload/getAllNoRepeatCommunicate.py
user      15557 15555  0 15:27 pts/18   00:00:00 /bin/bash -c if TERM=eterm-color script --quiet --flush --return --command "PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python python3 tool
user      15558 15557  0 15:27 pts/18   00:00:00 script --quiet --flush --return --command PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3
user      15559 15558 73 15:27 pts/19   01:54:08 python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/be
user      54970 15559 99 18:03 pts/19   00:00:18 python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/be
user      54974 15559 99 18:03 pts/19   00:00:15 python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/be
user      54975 15559 99 18:03 pts/19   00:00:16 python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/be
user      54976 15559 99 18:03 pts/19   00:00:15 python3 tools/train.py -c configs/rec/PP-OCRv3/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec.yml -o Global.pretrained_model=pretrain_models/ch_PP-OCRv3_rec_train/be
user      55410 31967  0 18:03 pts/11   00:00:00 grep --color=auto python3
```

The output seems to be limited to some max column. I did not find related settings for this.

I also tested in an `emacs -q` session and the issue still existed.

My emacs version is: `GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin21.5.0, Carbon Version 165 AppKit 2113.5) of 2022-07-04`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of a shell in Emacs is the width of the Emacs window the shell buffer is related to. If you want to get longer output lines, try something like `COLUMNS=1024 ps -ef | grep python3` in the shell buffer.